# Ubuntu 16.04.6 Desktop is not installing

Tags: system-installation, freeze

I am using using Lenovo IdeaPad S400 which has Windows 7 installed. 
I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (32 bit), but Ubuntu screen freezes during installation. 
I have tried booting the pendrive multiple times, but it didn't help.

What should I do in order to install Ubuntu on the machine?

Comment: What is the video adapter there?

Comment: is 64-bit available? `lscpu | grep op-code` it doese not make sense if your cpu can 64-bit to install a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable secure boot in windows 7? pls refer this video for the same - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qi4rOfpRugk

Also check your boot mode of windows 7, it will be either legacy or UEFI. Then make sure Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS is also of the same mode before installing.